# Excel Online - creating table changes date display to decimal

Tags: excel, date, datatable, automation

Once I create table in Excel Online

[image]

I get some side effect which is change of date display to decimal value:

[image]

To reverse this effect manually I just have to change current date format to anything else, then go back to the first one. Nothing really changes that way but date display gets back to normal.
The thing is I want to avoid this situation.

Any idea how to deal with this phenomena? Is it some bug or maybe it can be dealt with some office settings?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate your problem with office365.

Setting the whole column to a specific date format before generating the table keep the formatting to the generated table.

**Set specific date format:**

[image: Date format]